# How to make SELECT that returns TIMESTAMP and a value per minute within the current quarter hour?

Tags: oracle, select

I have a table as below, and I need select to return the value per minute within the current quarter. For example, if now it's 15:19, I need select to return TIMESTAMP and the value in this quarter between 15:15 and 15:30.
That is, I need select to return the last minutes of the current quarter of an hour. DB is ORACLE.

```
    TIMESTAMP    |    VALUE

11/11/2019 15:09  |     45

11/11/2019 15:10  |     10

11/11/2019 15:11  |     15

11/11/2019 15:12  |     35

11/11/2019 15:13  |     55

11/11/2019 15:14  |     25

11/11/2019 15:15  |     20

11/11/2019 15:16  |     22

11/11/2019 15:17  |     12

11/11/2019 15:18  |     10

11/11/2019 15:19  |     21
```

I have tried  TRUNC, but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `trunc` by 15 mins.

You can do it using following logic:

```
Select * from your_table
Where your_timestamp_col 
      between trunc(systimestamp,'dd') + floor(to_char(systimestamp,'sssss.ff') / 900) / 96
      And trunc(systimestamp,'dd') + ceil(to_char(systimestamp,'sssss.ff') / 900) / 96
```

Here, 900 represent seconds in 15 mins and 96 represents total such quarters in a day (24 hours * 4 quarters = 96)

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks!! And if my Timestamp Its 3 hours more than the real time, are there some way to correct it at query?

Comment: Yes add `+3/24`  after `trunc()`

Comment: Ye it works!!! I am  boring  you.... And if the interval  needed to start at 01 instead 00, minutes to 15, an 16 to 30, and 31 to 45... and like that....?

Comment: If this answer solved your question then please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, so that your question is marked as resolved.

Comment: `1/(24*3600)` represents 1 second. so you can add or subtract it from final value according to requirement

Comment: I am  receiving the return at java class: java.SQL.SQLException: ORA:01722 invalid  number  ,someone  know why?

Comment: The problem about Exception was the point at 'sssss.ff' i changed to comma and it works. Thanks a lot by the help!!